# How to create a voice using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, voice

Is there any simple way that I can create a text-to-speech function with JavaScript? Preferably, I would like it in this form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function createVoice(text) {
some JavaScript code
}
</script>
<a onclick="createVoice('Hello world')">Text-to-speech test</a>
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: you would probably need to make a call to the server which would render the speech like this one http://www.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php‎

Answer (score 0):

You need some external library. For example you could look at http://www.speechapi.com/apis/javascript/

Comment: Why would you need to use an external library? Why can't someone create their own?